# v-for not render any value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i use v-for to render title value with select input , but not return any value

my qcm array

```
 [{"_id":"1","title":"test qcm "},{"_id":"2","title":"kkkk"}]
```

select input

```
<select name="qcm_list" id="qcm_list"  required>
              <option value> QCM</option>
              <option
                v-for="item in qcm"
                :value="item._id"
                :key="item._id"
              >{{item.title}}</option>
 </select>
```

qcm array in vue

```
data() {
    return {
      qcm:[]
}}
axios.get('url')
.then(res=>{
this.qcm=res
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"not return any value"_? You aren't using `v-model` on your `<select>` so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i update my question

Comment: That's not exactly valid JS. When does that `axios` call run?

Comment: Still can't see any problem ~ https://jsfiddle.net/gvty03xs/

Comment: First thing put that Axios call in the mounted lifecycle and try to check the structure of return data whether it is JSON or not

Answer (score 3):

In axios, you must use *res.data* to get the *qcm* data, like this:

```
axios.get(url).then(res => {
    this.qcm = res.data
}).catch(err => {
    //handle when an error occur
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON structure is incorrect, you're missing a " after "_id it should be:

```
[{"_id":"1","title":"test qcm"},{"_id":"2","title":"kkkk"}]
```

Comment: copy paste problem .